# What is the recommended way to implement a high level clutter based listview?

Tags: listview, gnome, clutter

I would like to use a [clutter](https://blogs.gnome.org/clutter/) backed `Listview`.

The features I need are:

- multi-selection
- keyboard navigation
- scrolling
- lazy loading (like `Gtk.TreeView` with fixed height rows)

I've stumbled upon [Clutter.Model](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-1.0/Clutter.Model) that looks a lot like [Gtk.TreeModel](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeModel).

Is there any "high level" `clutter` ui components that uses `Model`?

**What is the recommended approach to have such features implemented with `clutter` based components?**

> **edit**: I found code showing how to use `Clutter.Model` in the [toys](https://github.com/clutter-project/toys) repository: [object-store](https://github.com/clutter-project/toys/tree/master/object-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClutterModel` and its concrete class `ClutterListModel` is just a simplified version of `GtkTreeModel` and `GtkListStore`. It's actually fairly useless on its own, and will likely be deprecated in Clutter 1.24.

There are no examples of Clutter actors using `ClutterModel`; some higher level toolkits, like [Mx](https://github.com/clutter-project/mx) and the Moblin/MeeGo netbook user experience had some widget displaying a `ClutterListModel`-backed list.